# React_on_rails with react-select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-select, react-on-rails

I am trying to use react-select inside my rails project.
I have a `gem 'react_on_rails'` installed and I am having a bit of a problem.

I installed `react-select` using `npm install` and wanted to `import Select from 'react-select'`, but then I get a lot of server errors starting

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'imports' in ...
```

along with web browser console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react"
```

How can I make this work? It seems that installing react-select using npm and using react_on_rails instead of pure react is a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This won't address your specific react-on-rail problems, but I managed to get react-select and react-rails working together. Have you looked into installing react-select via rails assets?

Eg:

`source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-react-select', "1.0.0.rc.1"
end`

I still had to poke around a fair bit because there appears to be a number of version incompatibility issues, but seems to be working now.